# Adding an email to an exitsen contact in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

so I've this database in postgres and I need to add a new email to my current contact.
How can I add this new email and keep as many emails as wanted in my database?
This is how my table looks like:
[image]

The table is called Address.
And this is what I want:

[image]

I want to add a new email address.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about an INSERT ? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the current content of the `address` column? It's not visible in the screen shot (it's better to present sample data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) anyway). It's also unclear to me if you want to add additional rows to the table (then use INSERT as Frank suggested) or if you want to append values to the `address` column

Comment: I've tried to do an Insert but how I identify what ID I want to add a new email?